How to exclude singularities for `NMinimize`
I have an messy expression and want to apply NMinimize to it, have no idea how to force NMinimize to ignore the singularities it complains about.
The code:
diff=973829./(Sqrt[1-E^(-NN^x2 x1)] NN)^(1/3)-2.35655*10^6 Sqrt[(1+(4.4289 (1-E^(-NN^x2 x1)) (-1+Log[(1+Sqrt[1-1. (1-E^(-NN^x2 x1))])/(1-Sqrt[1-1. (1-E^(-NN^x2 x1))])]/(2 Sqrt[1-1. (1-E^(-NN^x2 x1))])))/(1-1. (1-E^(-NN^x2 x1))))/NN];
objective = Sum[N[diff]^2, {NN, 1, 20}];
ParamNSQ=NMinimize[{objective,x1>0,x1<20,x2>0,x2<10},{x1,x2}];

It works for the restrictions {x1>0,x1<2,x2>0,x2<1}, but for {x1>0,x1<20,x2>0,x2<10} it returns errors.

If we take objective from @user64494 answer, we first check the region where objective \[Element] Reals
cond = FunctionDomain[objective, {x1, x2}];
pic=RegionPlot[cond, {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100, FrameLabel -> {x1, x2}]


Only your first region {x1>0,x1<2,x2>0,x2<1} nearly fits into this domain.
reg1 =
  Region[Style[
    RegionBoundary[
     ImplicitRegion[x1 > 0 && x1 < 2 && x2 > 0 && x2 < 1, {x1, x2}] ],
     Darker[Green]]];
reg2 =
  Region[Style[
    RegionBoundary[
     ImplicitRegion[
      x1 > 0 && x1 < 20 && x2 > 0 && x2 < 10, {x1, x2}] ], Red]];
Show[{pic, reg1, reg2}]


Perhaps you know how to restrict your second domain problem adapted?

The following works without any errors and warnings in 14.0 on Windows 10. We use exact numbers to avoid problems with the evaluation.
diff = Rationalize[973829./(Sqrt[1 - E^(-NN^x2  x1)]  NN)^(1/3) - 
2.35655*10^6  Sqrt[(1 + (4.4289  (1 - E^(-NN^x2  x1))  (-1 + 
          Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 - 1.  (1 - E^(-NN^x2  x1))])/(1 - 
               Sqrt[1 - 1.  (1 - E^(-NN^x2  x1))])]/(2  Sqrt[
              1 - 1.  (1 - E^(-NN^x2  x1))])))/(1 - 
        1.  (1 - E^(-NN^x2  x1))))/NN], 0];
objective = Sum[diff^2, {NN, 1, 20}];
NMinimize[{objective, x1 > 0, x1 < 20, x2 > 0, x2 < 10}, {x1, x2}]


{7.50014*10^8, {x1 -> 0.00448925, x2 -> 0.814362}}

Of course, there is no guaranty that the global minimum is found.

Thank you for the comment. The solution proposed does not work on Win 10, Mathematica ver. 13.0.1.

@seva011: Up to the documentation to NMinimize (see the bottom of the page), the command was updated in 2022 (13.2).

Got it, but currently I have no opportunity to update it. So looking for other means.
